# How to fix 6 high severity vulnerabilities npm audit fix --force

Tags: security, npm, create-react-app, audit, npx

I'm getting above mentioned error and it says to address all issues (including breaking changes), run audit fix --force

when i run `npm audit command`, it gives following details

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-18T17_42_41_740Z-debug-0.log
```